# I'm trying to import a csv into PGAdmin 4. It has date columns in DD/MM/YYYY, but I get this error: date/time field value out of range: "20/01/2010"

Tags: pgadmin-4, postgresql-12

This is the error mesaage I get when I try to import the csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQqx6.png)

I have tried to change the date style of the date columns before importing the data, but I also get another error message:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
ALTER COLUMN date_of_booking TYPE date USING date::date DateStyle('DMY')
ALTER COLUMN check_in_date TYPE date USING date::date DateStyle('DMY')
ALTER COLUMN check_out_date TYPE date USING date::date DateStyle('DMY');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROHcj.png)

Comment: Maybe this [question ("How to set Postgresql database to see date as "MDY" permanently")](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19679/228233) in dba.stackexchange can help you? Though it seems to be about setting date format for the entire database, not specific columns